# Scraping group title from Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some information from this page here:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/574916095895510/?fref=ts

When you click "See all", the members list is displayed. I'm trying to get the following text: "Members of UCLA class of 2018 Official Group".

However, I get the following error when I try to print the text from the XPath:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "scraper.py", line 35, in <module>
        print title.text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

When I dump the session as an image, the title is visible, so I know that the text is available for scraping.

Here is my full code:

```
import time
import dryscrape
import json
import ast

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

# set up a web scraping session
sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/')

# visit homepage and log in
print "Logging in..."
sess.visit('/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgroups%2F574916095895510%2F%3Ffref%3Dts')

# Set username and password
username_field = sess.at_css('#email')
password_field = sess.at_css('#pass')
username_field.set(username)
password_field.set(password)

# Submit the form
username_field.form().submit()

# Wait
time.sleep(3)

print "Viewing all members..."
see_all_button = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="pagelet_group_profile_members"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a')
see_all_button.click()

time.sleep(3)

title = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="u_z_0"]/div/div[1]/h3')
print title.text()

sess.render('fb.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to scrap data from Facebook.
Facebook provide all your data needs through their API.

You can find any of the group info in their documentation here. This is much cleaner than scraping and will be maintained if you want to use it in future. :)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group

I have done a lot of scraping and this doesn't seem like a good use case for scraping - use the API!

Comment: you could include the scraping TOS in your answer: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php